# Redirecting image links to a php file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to re-write a direct linked image link to point to a php file?

from http ://...../picture.jpg to http ://....../load.php?file= picture.jpg

Can it be done using mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.jpg)$ /load.php?file=$1 [L]
```

if you want to redirect all images you can add other extensions :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp))$ /load.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done. Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ /load.php?file=$1 [L]
```